# The rules of list references?

Tags: python

I got really confused on the list reference in python. Please help me understand. a simple case as below:

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = [1, 2]
arr1.append(arr2)
#arr2[0] = 5
arr2 = [6]
print(arr1)
```

So after append `arr2` to `arr1` without deep copy, to my understanding any change on `arr2` would be reflected in `arr1`. However, only changing components like `arr2[0] = 5` updates the `arr1`, while `arr2 = [6]` won't. Any reason why?

Comment: `arr2 = [6]` creates an entirely new list and assigns it to the name arr2, nothing to do with the list arr2 used to refer to and arr1 still does. I'd recommend using e.g. http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: `arr2 = [6]` doesn't mutate anything. Also note, none of these behaviors have anything to do with lists. The semantics of Python doesn't make special cases based on the type of object imvolved

Comment: Anyway, read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to my understanding any change on arr2 would be reflected in arr1

This is true for mutation, but assigning a new object to a label does not mutate the object, you are going to create a new list object `[6]` in memory and assign it to that label. `arr2` now points to this new object(with different `id()`) not the one stored in `arr1`.

List objects are mutable so you can mutate them with lets say `.append()` method. In this case, any change to `arr2` using `.append()` will reflect the list stored in `arr1`

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = [1, 2]
arr1.append(arr2)

arr2.append(6)
print(arr1)
```

Anytime you want to check if they are the same objects or not, simply print ids before and after. In case of mutation:

```
print(id(arr1[0])) # 2157378023744
print(id(arr2))    # 2157378023744
```

Comment: `is` is usually a better way

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, better than dealing with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `arr2 = [6]`, you create a new list object that is now referenced by arr2. The reference in the list still points to the initial list, so you cannot use the label arr2 anymore to change the contents of the list referenced in arr1.